# In this link I am not getting why is An is finite?

Tags: continuity

In this link, I am not getting why is $A_n$ is finite? 
[Prove that function is continuous in all irrational points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898892/prove-that-function-is-continuous-in-all-irrational-points)

Why is the number of such positive integers at most $[\frac {1} {\epsilon}]$ , the integral part of ${1\over\epsilon}$? 
And why is the set of all those rationals numbers
 $\frac pq \in (0,1)$ with $\frac 1q \geq \epsilon $ is 
$ \{\frac pq : 1\le q \lt [\frac 1\epsilon] ,1 \le p \lt q\}$?
And most important of all
they call this (or denote this) set afterwards by , 
$\{r_k=  {{p_k}\over{q_k}} : 1 \le k \le N\}$.

I got the idea of the proof, but not getting the actual proof; why are all these happening?

Comment: Finiteness of $A_n$ follows from the fact that $1/n\to 0$

Comment: No but it has to be related with $\epsilon$ in $\epsilon \delta $ definition

Comment: Given $\epsilon>0\;\; \exists N\in \Bbb N\; $ such that $|1/n-0|<\epsilon\;\;\forall n \ge N \implies 1/n<\epsilon \;\;\forall n\ge N\implies1/n\ge \epsilon $ for $n=1,...N-1$

Comment: Ok so this is N. What about $p_k and q_k$ appeared suddenly? There are other links like this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530097/proof-of-continuity-of-thomae-function-at-irrationals but none of them contains this type of arguments.

Comment: Once you know that a (non-empty) set $S$ is finite, say with size $N$, you can enumerate it, yielding $S=\{s_k\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant N\}$. Is this your question?

Comment: yes,this is one of the ques,this is clear.